osm2pgsql error: Connecting to database failed (context=check)
I got this error while importing an osm file to PostgreSQL directly.
My code is:
osm2pgsql –c –d highway -U postgres –P postgres –W postgres -H localhost  "D:\data\highway.osm"

The result shows:
ERROR: Connecting to database failed (context=check): connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied


Do I need a style file to fix this error?

Port number "postgres" is certainly invalid. By default it is 5432. Follow the documentation https://osm2pgsql.org/doc/manual.html#running-osm2pgsql.

Thank user30184. I updated it but I got a new error.
Password:
osm2pgsql version 1.11.0
ERROR: Connecting to database failed (context=check): connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
